# Как установить API 30 (31, 32) для Unity 2017?

Tags: unity3d-android

Имеется у меня проект на Unity 2017.4.40f1. Это последняя версия для 2017 года. До последних обновлений на Play Market Google нормально публиковался. Однако, после крайнего обновления маркет просит обновить API по крайней мере до 30. Захожу в настройки билда и мы видим такую картину - API выше значения 29 просто нет в списке! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я установил последнюю версию Андроид студио, установил все возможные API, но в настройках они так и не появились! Как быть!? Неужели это решается только обновлением Unity до более свежей версии?

Comment: А в build у вас прописано sdkversion 31?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, да, нужно обновлять Unity до более новой версии. Вот [здесь](https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-unity-2017-supported-android-api-level-30.1165960/) была такая же проблема, там также указали список всех доступных API для последней версии 2017 ([линк](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/AndroidSdkVersions.html)). :(

Comment: Ох... Весь проект перелопачивать заново ((( Сейчас буду переустанавливать и смотреть, как быть дальше

Comment: Желаю удачи с проектом :)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, это действительно помогло. Однако, появилось много других проблем. Изменений в скриптах почти не было, а вот собрать не могу теперь.. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1374479/467156

Answer (score 0):

Можно обновить. По крайней мере работает для версий `Unity` от 2017 до 2022.

Для этого я устанавливаю `Android Studio` и скачиваю нужные `SDK`.

После иду по адресу:
`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms` и копирую нужные папки.

Следующий шаг - нужно найти где хранится таже папка `platforms` у `Unity`:

`C:\ProgramFiles\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms`

B вставляем в папку скопированные решения. После открываем `Build Stting` и определяем версию `Android` (система должна определить те что лежат в данной папке).