# Как исправить ошибки компиляции? gradle

Tags: gradle

После того, как перешел с Unity 2017 на 2020, исправил все ошибки и подтянул новые SDK, NDK, JDK и gradle, пытаюсь собрать свой проект и встречаюсь сразу с несколькими ошибками, ума которым дать не могу. Для начал - выходит вот такое окошко,

[image: ОШИБКА GRADLE]

а потом в консоли появляются эти ошибки:

**ВО ПЕРВЫХ:**

> Configure project :launcher
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
> It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> You will no longer be able to disable R8
> Build-tool 32.0.0 is missing DX at D:\AndroidSDK\build-tools\32.0.0\dx.bat
> Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
> --- много похожих друг на друга строк ---
> Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
> Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
> Mapping new ns http://schemas.android

**ВО ВТОРЫХ:**

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:bundleReleaseResources'.

> Installed Build Tools revision 32.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

**В-ТРЕТЬИХ:**

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.26f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\gradle-7.3.3\lib\gradle-launcher-7.3.3.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:bundleReleaseResources'.

> Installed Build Tools revision 32.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
]
stdout[

> Configure project :launcher
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
> It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> You will no longer be able to disable R8
> Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
> --- МНОГО ПОХОЖИХ ДРУГ НА ДРУГА СТРОК ---
> Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sd

**В-ЧЕТВЕРТЫХ:**

Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 59 seconds (59038 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Кучу постов уже просмотрел, но решения так и не нашел. Как быть, ребят?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласен с отрицательной оценкой вопроса. Достаточно было ПОЛНОСТЬЮ снести всё, что связано с Unity старой версии. Все файлы NDK, JDK, SDK! Саму версию, при этом, раз уж зацепили настройки и новую версию, ее тоже пришлось полностью снести. И только после этого необходимо установить новый UnityHub, который установит саму программу и предоставит возможность дополнить ее необходимыми инструментами.